# check the cellphone setting permission under API level 23

Tags: android, permissions

How can I check the permission under API level 23,in the presence of the cellphone setting gives a rejected permission.
For example,even the camera permission is rejected,though I can take photo in my app[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFvtT.png)